# how to fix attribute error : 'None type' object has no attribute next

Tags: python, attributes

When I run this I am getting the following error in while loop:

> Attribute error: 'None type ' has no attributes 'next'

```py
# Method lo delete a node at a particular position
def deleteatpos(self, pos):
    count = 0
    currentnode = self.head
    previousnode = self.head
    if pos > self.length or pos < 0:
        print("The position does not exist. Please enter a valid position")
    else:
        while currentnode.next != None or count < pos:
            count = count + 1
            if count == pos + 1:
                previousnode.next = currentnode.next # or 
                previousnode.setNext(currentnode.getNext)
                currentnode.next.previous = previousnode # or 
                currentnode.getNext.setprevious(previous)
                self.length -= 1
                return
            else:
                previousnode = currentnode
                currentnode = currentnode.next
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of this error is **probably you are using a non defined property of a object**. for example if have a node object that has three property let say `val, next, previous`. Now if you are trying to access a property that is not there in the nodes property that will throw an error stating that there is no attribute.

Now coming to your question, according to the error, your `node does not have a property called next`, so cant access it. for example you can not use `node.next`. for that you to define it first.